# How to detect in post.message null var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I need detect if child.php not send message to parent.php, I use the post.message . 
I try with:

```
if (message == null), == false, == "", but not work ..
```

My code:

parent.php (get the message "work" from child.php if its open)

```
<button id="open-child-window-2">Open Child Window</button>

<script>

var __CHILD_WINDOW_HANDLE_2 = null;

$("#open-child-window-2").on('click', function() {
    __CHILD_WINDOW_HANDLE_2 = window.open('child-2.php', '_blank');
});


window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    ProcessChildMessage_2(e.data);
} , false);


function ProcessChildMessage_2(message) {
    alert(message);
}

</script>
```

child.php (send to parent.php the message "work" every 0.5 seconds)

```
<script>

setInterval(function(){

    window.opener.postMessage("work", "*");

},500);

</script>
```

I need detect if chiel.php not send "work" to parent.php, for example:

1. if closed the child.php
2. if go another page from the child.php

Thanks you so much

Comment: So your real purpose is to detect closing or exiting the page?

Comment: yes, the exit to another page. The closed i have work it with child.closed

Answer (score 0):

Then why don’t you use `[window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)`?
<s>(Yesterday my reputation is 53 and it fell to 49 again today so I can’t comment.)</s>